# CodeIgniter - Retrieve data from MySQL and display without refreshing the page

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

Currently I'm trying to use CodeIgniter to **display the comment or post after inputted by user and display it without refreshing the page**.

I had been searching for the answer for few days and I still can't get any appropriate answer for my project.

Sorry to say that I'm still new on using CodeIgniter and JQuery. Because the objective of this project want us to learn new programming language.

This is the code from my VIEW, I extract the main code

```
<?php
    foreach ($comment as $comments) {
        if ($comments['PostID'] == $stickynote['PostID']) {
?>
<div style="background-color: lightblue; border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;  margin-bottom: 5px; width: 70%; height: 80px">
    <a class="pull-left" href="#">
        <!-- Profile Picture -->
        <img style='margin-top: 9px; margin-left: 5px; border-radius: 5px; padding-left: 5px;' class="media-object" id="sub-photo" src="../../images/<?php echo $profile ?>" alt="<?php echo $profile ?>" alt="...">
    </a>
    <div class="media-body">
        <!-- Display Username -->
        <h4 class="media-heading"><?php echo $comments['FirstName'] ?></h4>
        <p style="width: 500px; word-wrap:break-word;">
        <?php echo $comments['Description'] ?>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
<?php
    } <!-- End of IF statement -->
} <!-- End of FOR LOOP -->
?>
```

This is my CONTROLLER

```
public function college_garden() {

    $this -> load -> model('LoginModel');

    if ($this -> session -> userdata('logged_in')) {

        $session_data = $this -> session -> userdata('logged_in');
        $data['username'] = $session_data['username'];

        $data = array(
            'comment' => $this -> CommentModel -> readComment($data['username'])
        );

        $this -> load -> view('include/header');
        $this -> load -> view('college_garden', $data);
        $this -> load -> view('include/footer');

    } else {

        redirect('main', 'refresh');

    }
}
```

This is my MODEL

```
public function readComment($studentID) {

    $this -> db -> select('PostID, Description, FirstName, LastName, PostTime, Image');
    $this -> db -> from('Comment');
    $this -> db -> join('CollegeUser', 'CollegeUser.StudentID = Comment.StudentID');
    $this -> db -> join('PhotoGallery', 'PhotoGallery.PhotoID = CollegeUser.PhotoID');
    $this -> db -> order_by("Comment.PostTime", "desc");

    return $this -> db -> get() -> result_array();
}
```

Thank you for those who helping me. Cheer.

Comment: inputted by user ?? where is your form so user can input the comments ??

Comment: Learn `Ajax` first mate, here are some links: 1) http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ , 2) http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/

Comment: @Bipen, actually there is a form_open() at there. But I didn't show it out. Sorry.

Comment: @Nil'z, yeah. Trying hard right now. >_<

Answer (score 0):

To submit a form without refreshing, you're going to need to use ajax.

something like this:

```
$("form").on("submit", function(){
  $.post("submit.php", $(this).serialize(), function(){
    ..your code to display comments/post..
  });
return false;
});
```

The part to display comments/posts are entirely up to you, you can either do another ajax to query the server and fetch the post, or just output `$("textarea").val();` if you're lazy.